# Override the HTML table border attribute

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, inline

I have a table with the attribute "Border" set to 0 so whatever I set in the css the table don't show a border

Notice that I can't change the table border attribute inline. I can't access the file.

```
<table  class="ms-listviewtable" handledeleteinit="true" border="0" style="">
```

What can I do to override the border ?

Comment: Have you tried using the following css code: `.ms-listviewtable{ border: 1px solid #000000 !important; }`? It's funny actually. In PHP ! before something means not... xD

Comment: try to use this code: table {border: 1px solid red !important;}

Comment: @shadeed9 don't use table! Than it will set for all the tables in the page. And this table does have a class! So use the class instead!

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl Yes I agree, but this is only a test to see what the result :)

Comment: !important don't work and as I said I can't modify the table attribute I don't have access to the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found is to add a border in th and td, but to have the same expected result I have to set  only 1 border side.

otherwise I will get a bold border.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of Temala's answer:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
td, th {
     border-right: 1px solid red;
     border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```